# MapView Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, mapkit

I have written simple mapView application.It is showing two kind of problems.

1- Execution is stopping on Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error.

2- This function is showing compile time error .

```
- (IBAction)findMe:(id)sender {

     If( [[toggleButton titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqualToString:@"Find Me"] )
     {
     [toggleButton setTitle:@"Hide Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
     }
     else
     {
     [toggleButton setTitle:@"Find Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     mapView.showsUserLocation=NO;
     }

}
```

How to remove these error ?

I want put coordinates of more then one location in my code i want to show loc.png icon on map corresponding to those coordinates how i can accomplish this task?

You can see the sample project from this link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5pNDpbvZ8SnRmNFS0pjVnJFWHc

Comment: You are using a capital I in "If". It should be "if", that could be the cause of compile time error.

Comment: Compile time errors are removed. Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error persist at runtime.

Comment: @user2557829 this question is answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45067276/thread-1-signal-sigabrt-error/45069255#45069255

Answer (score 0):

You are getting compile time error for 3 reasons:

1) The "If" you are using in if-else condition should be "if" i.e lowercase.

2). You have an IBOutlet connect to findMe button in storyboard which do not exist in your view controller. So either remove it or add it.

3)You are using MKMapView but you didn't added the MapKit Framework in "Link Binaries" in build phases option of your project.

Please do all these steps to have your code compiled & executed error free.

Comment: Compile time errors are removed. Program execution is still stopping at runtime on Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error.

Comment: I want put coordinates of more then one location in my code i want to show loc.png icon on map corresponding to those coordinates how i can accomplish this task?

Comment: Program execution is stopping because in main.stroyboard you have an IBOutlet connected to findMe button which doesn't exist in your controller class. Unless you remove the linking of that findMe IBOutlet your code wouldn't be passed through runtime validations.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to your query:**
I want put coordinates of more then one location in my code i want to show loc.png icon on map corresponding to those coordinates how i can accomplish this task?

**Here is the code for ViewController.h**

```html
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate>

@end
```

**Here is the code for ViewController.m**

```html
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyAnnotation.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *myMapView;

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // setup the map view, delegate and current location

    [self.myMapView setDelegate:self];

    self.myMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D myLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(25.085130,-77.331428);
    [self.myMapView setCenterCoordinate:myLocation];

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(myLocation, 2000, 2000);
    region.center = self.myMapView.centerCoordinate;
    self.myMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [self.myMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

    [self dropPins];
}

-(void)dropPins {
    NSMutableArray *annotationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location1 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(25.085130, -77.331428);
    MyAnnotation *annotation1 = [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinates:location1 image:@"loc.png"];
    [annotationArray addObject:annotation1];
    [self.myMapView addAnnotations:annotationArray];

    [annotationArray removeAllObjects];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location2 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(25.085130, -77.336428);
    MyAnnotation *annotation2 = [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinates:location2 image:@"loc.png"];
    [annotationArray addObject:annotation2];
    [self.myMapView addAnnotations:annotationArray];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]])
    {
        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.myMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

        if (annotationView == nil)
        {
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        } else
        {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;

        if([[(MyAnnotation *)annotationView.annotation image] isEqualToString:@"pin1.png"])
            annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loc.png"];

        if([[(MyAnnotation *)annotationView.annotation image] isEqualToString:@"pin2.png"])
            annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loc.png"];

        return annotationView;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**Add new files MyAnnotation.h/MyAnnotation.m**

**Here is the code for MyAnnotation.h**

```html
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MyAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *image;


-(id)initWithCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) paramCoordinates
                   image:(NSString *) paramImage;

@end
```

**Here is the code for MyAnnotation.m**

```html
#import "MyAnnotation.h"

@implementation MyAnnotation

-(id)initWithCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)paramCoordinates
                   image:(NSString *)paramImage
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil)
    {
        _coordinate = paramCoordinates;
        _image = paramImage;
    }
    return (self);
}

@end
```